# Flink RMQSource

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, apache-flink

I want to test RMQSource class for receiving data from RabbitMQ, but i don´t know how to config the Rabbit virtual host for my exchange, and i think is the problem i have. My code:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.RMQSource
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema

object rabbitjob {
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val stream = env.addSource(new RMQSource[String]("192.168.1.11", 5672,"user","pass", "inbound.input.data",false, new SimpleStringSchema())).print


def main (args:Array[String]){
    env.execute("Test Rabbit")
 }
}
```

Error in IntelliJ IDE: 
`Error:(10, 29) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String]
  val stream = env.addSource(new RMQSource[String]("192.168.1.11", 5672,"user","pass", "inbound.input.data",false, new SimpleStringSchema())).print`

`^`

`Error:(10, 29) not enough arguments for method addSource: (implicit evidence$7: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[String].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$7.
  val stream = env.addSource(new RMQSource[String]("192.168.1.11", 5672,"user","pass", "inbound.input.data",false, new SimpleStringSchema())).print`

`^`

Any idea how to solve it or alternatives??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are asking. Do you want to create the vhost and exchange? Or do you already have that and want to pass it in the code? Or something third?

Comment: I already have a vhost and exchange, and i want to pass it in my code

Comment: What is the name of the vhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is a Scala compile time error caused by some needed imports not being there.  Whenever you are using the Flink Scala API you should include the following:

`import org.apache.flink.api.scala._`

This will solve the compile time problem you're having.

Comment: `Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:4391', transport: 'socket'`
`Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:4391', transport: 'socket'`
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStreamSink`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink`
`Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`

Comment: How are running this?  Can you provide some more details?  Are you running in Intellij, local cluster, remote-cluster, etc..  How are you submitting your job?

Comment: I´m running it in IntelliJ, i want to consume Json from a RabbitMQ exchange queue

Comment: The goal is to compile it, and run it in a Yarn-Flink cluster. Dependencies: `org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11:1.0.3, org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11:1.1-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11:1.0.3, org.apache.flink:flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.11:1.1-SNAPSHOT`
MANIFEST.MF: `Class-Path: scala-library.jar rabbitmq-client.jar`

Comment: I noticed from your dependencies list above that you are mixing Flink 1.0.3 dependencies with 1.1-SNAPSHOT dependencies.  This could be the cause of the errors you're now seeing.  I would straighten that out and try again.

Comment: Thank you Jamie, the solution was the import you said, and put the rabbit-connector dependency in the profile for packaging JAR files in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Things changed over time.
Please have a look at [RMQConnectionConfig](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-connectors/flink-connector-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/rabbitmq/common/RMQConnectionConfig.java): here you can find the way to specify a virtual host through builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the vhost name as well. Take a look at [AMQP URI spec](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html).

In your case the whole AMQP URI would look like would be `"user:pass@192.168.1.11:5672/TestVHost"`.

Comment: This is good if you are using RabbitMQ lib, but with [Flink connector](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-connectors/flink-connector-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/rabbitmq/RMQSource.java)...

Comment: If that lib doesn't support vhost, you shouldn't use it. No one should.

Comment: So the question is how to use RabbitMQ lib in a Flink context

Comment: Well, change the source. In the link you provided RMQ java client is used, so simply extended Flink with a function that includes vhost parameter. Why don't you use official RMQ java client anyhow? (just curious)

Comment: Could you give me an example please, i´m not a java developer. The reason is because i´m doing a PoC with Flink and i want to test the native method

Comment: It's easier to to PoC with official rabbitmq java client. You already have the examples written. But if you want to.. In the file provided change the constructor, so that it has `String vhost` which you assign to the member attribute with the same name. And change the `initializeConnection` method (which is private, so you cannot extend actually) to call `factory.setVhost(vhost);`, the same way it's done for username etc...

Comment: Thank you, i did it, it was my alternative, but now i want to run it in a Flink stream context....

Comment: You are welcome! And since you are new: according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty I guess I wouldn't seem to bad if I ask for upvote and accept :)